# Unable to 'Close' Modal Popup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im unable to close a modal, when i access my intended URL i get presented with a Modal Popup. 
1. I have tried waiting and clicking on the element
2. also tried close via 'Alert' code
3. all were unsuccessful at closing the popup 
[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help,

[image]

Comment: is the modal in a separate iframe?

Comment: @cathal thanks for the reply, from what i can see im unable to identify any iframes, please see the latest image attatched

Comment: Can you show me how your selecting the WebElement?

Comment: @cathal its:      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button_ClosePopupPage));
        button_ClosePopupPage.click();

Comment: @cathal please also find my locator listed: public @FindBy(css=".close") WebElement button_ClosePopupPage;

Comment: Thanks Phil, last question. are any errors thrown while waiting for the element to be visible? or while attempting to click it?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply @cathal I get a timeout error that the element is not visible / locator able when the expected time elapses/

Answer (score 0):

```
check , whether it is separate window, if it it then will code might be work 


private static Object Handle1;
private static Object Handle2;

public static void switchToWindowsPopup() {
    Set<String> handles = DriverManager.getCurrent().getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itr = handles.iterator();
    Handle1 = itr.next();
   Handle2 = Handle1;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        lastHandle = itr.next();
    }
    DriverManager.getCurrent().switchTo().window(Handle2.toString());
}

public static void switchToMainWindow() {
    DriverManager.getCurrent().switchTo().window(Handle1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code might help you -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'CLOSE')]")).click();
```

or use `JavascriptExecuter` in this way -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='close']"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that in order to close the dialog, you need to hit the "x". Im assuming this because you are waiting for the button element to become clickable, but it never does. So, id suggest making your locator more specific:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='close']/span")
WebElement closeButton;
```

Please let me know, if this works..or what happens if it does not.

Comment: Your `XPath` is invalid: you should use `@class='close'` instead of `@class=='close'`

Comment: Thanks all @Saurabh Gaur method has worked, would anyone know why I would get the popup appearing during a different stage of the user journey using Firefox and geckodriver but the popup dosnt reappear when attempting to sign in via Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

From comment

> thanks for the fast reply @cathal I get a timeout error that the element is not visible / locator able when the expected time elapses

**Actually Your locator does not return unique result**. There are multiple `close button` element which have same class name `close`.

Unfortunately you'r getting invisible dialog `close button`, that's why you are in trouble.

You should try something as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".close")));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to continuously check for popups and therefore close?